# c# and jQuery How do I sanitize username\password fields

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-injection

c# (server) jQuery(for client) How do I sanitize username\password fields: only allows characters, no such thing as ";" for example. so no SQL injection will be possible

Comment: You shouldn't need to sanitize passwords - they should be hashed and stored using bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: Always use parameterised queries which should sanitise the input to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: If you're using something like Entity Framework to connect to your database then it will do the parameterisation which phuzi mentioned automatically for you when you save your object. If you're using ADO.NET then you need to use SqlParameter objects (or the equivalent for your database platform) - plenty of tutorials will show examples of this.

Comment: Naive restriction of input characters will not prevent all types of injection, and also you're just restricting what users can type - these characters might be valid, not just in passwords but in other things like free text fields - all your fields need to be free from the risk of injection, not just username/passwords. Don't restrict the input characters (or at least, not for this reason) - parameterisation is the correct solution, as you'd see if you'd researhced SQL injection online for yourself in any detail.

Comment: also instead of bcrypt or scrypt, you can follow the current hype and use argon2 as hashing function.

Comment: And yes you should also be hashing passwords as mentioned above. Storing passwords in plain-text is a security risk in itself.

Comment: @Isitar I wasn't aware of Argon2 - something for me to take a look at, cheers

Comment: As @ADyson mentioned, there should be no restriction on what a user uses as a password other than minimum length and perhaps checking it against [Troy Hunt's Pwned Passwords service](https://www.troyhunt.com/pwned-passwords-v3-is-now-live/)